# How to call multiple jquery function from .cs file?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have 2 JQuery functions which I want to call from PageLoad event. The current implementation is as under

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), 
"script", "Function1();", true);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), 
"script", "Function2();", true);
```

The problem is that, the first function is invoked i.e. Function1 and not Function2.

If I change the order of invocation, then  Function2 and not Function1 is called.

How to execute both the functions ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably overwritting *previous* script block with *later* as you have same key `script` for both blocks in [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558(v=vs.110).aspx) call. Give unique name to each script block e.g. name first block as `script1` and second as `script2` will allow you to call both functions.

```
SriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script1", "Function1();", true);

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script2", "Function2();", true);
```

In this particular scenario you do not need to register script block twice rather you can have multiple javascript stements in one `RegisterStartupScript`.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", 
                                    "Function1();Function2();", true);
```